# JOIN other table only if condition is true for ALL joined rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables I'm trying to conditionally `JOIN`.

`dbo.Users` looks like this:

```
UserID
------
24525
5425
7676
```

`dbo.TelemarketingCallAudits` looks like this (date format dd/mm/yyyy):

```
UserID Date       CampaignID
------ ---------- ----------
24525  21/01/2018 1
24525  26/08/2018 1
24525  17/02/2018 1
24525  12/01/2017 2
5425   22/01/2018 1
7676   16/11/2017 2
```

I'd like to return a table that contains ONLY users that I called at least 30 days ago (if `CampaignID`=1) and at least 70 days ago (if `CampaignID`=2).

The end result should look like this (today is 02/09/18):

```
UserID Date       CampaignID
------ ---------- ----------
5425   22/01/2018 1
7676   16/11/2017 2
```

- Note that because I called user 24524 with Campaign 1 only 7 days ago, I shall not see the user at all.

I tried this simple AND/OR condition and then I found out it will still return the users I shouldn't see because they do have rows indicating other calls and it simply ignoring the conditioned calls... which misses the goal obviously.

I have no idea on how to condition the overall appearance of the user if ANY of his associated rows in the second table did not meet the condition.

```
AND 
(
    internal_TelemarketingCallAudits.CallAuditID IS NULL --No telemarketing calls is fine
    OR 
    (
        internal_TelemarketingCallAudits.CampaignID = 1 --Campaign 1
        AND 
        DATEADD(dd, 75, MAX(internal_TelemarketingCallAudits.Date)) < GETDATE() --Last call occured at least 10 days ago
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        internal_TelemarketingCallAudits.CampaignID != 1 --Other campaigns
        AND 
        DATEADD(dd, 10, MAX(internal_TelemarketingCallAudits.Date)) < GETDATE() --Last call occured at least 10 days ago
    )
 )
```

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/49759/2)

```
select *
from dbo.Users u
inner join ( --get the most recent call per user (taking into account different campaign timescales)
    select tca.UserId
    , tca.CampaignId
    , tca.[Date]
    , case when DateAdd(Day,c.DaysSinceLastCall, tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end LastCalledInWindow
    , row_number() over (partition by tca.UserId order by case when DateAdd(Day,c.DaysSinceLastCall, tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, tca.[Date] desc) r
    from dbo.TelemarketingCallAudits tca
    inner join (
        values (1, 60)
        , (2, 70)
    ) c (CampaignId, DaysSinceLastCall)
    on tca.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
) mrc
on mrc.UserId = u.UserId
and mrc.r = 1 --only accept the most recent call
and mrc.LastCalledInWindow = 0 --only include if they haven't been contacted in the last x days
```

I'm not comparing all rows here; but rather saw that you're interested in when the most recent call is; then you only care if that's in the X day window.  There's a bit of additional complexity given the X days varies by campaign; so it's not the most recent call you care about so much as the most likely to fall within that window.  To get around that, I sort each users' calls by those which are in the window first followed by those which aren't; then sort by most recent first within those 2 groups.  This gives me the field `r`.

By filtering on `r = 1` for each user, we only get the most recent call (adjusted for campaign windows).  By filtering on `LastCalledInWindow = 0` we exclude those who have been called within the campaign's window.

NB: I've used an inner query (aliased `c`) to hold the campaign ids and their corresponding windows.  In reality you'd probably want a campaigns table holding that same information instead of coding inside the query itself.

Hopefully everything else is self-explanatory; but give me a nudge in the comments if you need any further information.

---

### UPDATE

Just realised you'd also said "no calls is fine"... Here's a tweaked version to allow for scenarios where the person has not been called.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b247/1).

```
    select *
    from dbo.Users u
    left outer join ( --get the most recent call per user (taking into account different campaign timescales)
        select tca.UserId
        , tca.CampaignId
        , tca.[Date]
        , case when DateAdd(Day,c.DaysSinceLastCall, tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end LastCalledInWindow
        , row_number() over (partition by tca.UserId order by case when DateAdd(Day,c.DaysSinceLastCall, tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, tca.[Date] desc) r
        from dbo.TelemarketingCallAudits tca
        inner join (
            values (1, 60)
            , (2, 70)
        ) c (CampaignId, DaysSinceLastCall)
        on tca.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
    ) mrc
    on mrc.UserId = u.UserId
    where 
    (
        mrc.r = 1 --only accept the most recent call
        and mrc.LastCalledInWindow = 0 --only include if they haven't been contacted in the last x days
    )
    or mrc.r is null --no calls at all
```

---

## Update: Including a default campaign offset

To include a default, you could do something like the code below ([SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04543/1)).  Here, I've put each campaign's offset value in the `Campaigns` table, but created a default campaign with `ID = -1` to handle anything for which there is no offset defined.  I use a `left join` between the audit table and the campaigns table so that we get all records from the audit table, regardless of whether there's a campaign defined, then a `cross join` to get the default campaign.  Finally, I use a `coalesce` to say "if the campaign isn't defined, use the default campaign".

```
select *
from dbo.Users u
left outer join ( --get the most recent call per user (taking into account different campaign timescales)
    select tca.UserId
    , tca.CampaignId
    , tca.[Date]
    , case when DateAdd(Day,coalesce(c.DaysSinceLastCall,dflt.DaysSinceLastCall), tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end LastCalledInWindow
    , row_number() over (partition by tca.UserId order by case when DateAdd(Day,coalesce(c.DaysSinceLastCall,dflt.DaysSinceLastCall), tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, tca.[Date] desc) r
    from dbo.TelemarketingCallAudits tca
    left outer join Campaigns c
    on tca.CampaignId = c.CampaignId
    cross join Campaigns dflt
    where dflt.CampaignId = -1
) mrc
on mrc.UserId = u.UserId
where 
(
    mrc.r = 1 --only accept the most recent call
    and mrc.LastCalledInWindow = 0 --only include if they haven't been contacted in the last x days
)
or mrc.r is null --no calls at all
```

That said, I'd recommend not using a default, but rather ensuring that every campaign has an offset defined.  i.e. Presumably you already have a campaigns table; and since this offset value is defined per campaign, you can include a field in that table for holding this offset.  Rather than leaving this as `null` for some records, you could set it to your default value; thus simplifying the logic / avoiding potential issues elsewhere where that value may subsequently be used.

---

You'd also asked about the `order by` clause.  There is no `order by 1/0`; so I assume that's a typo.  Rather the full statement is `row_number() over (partition by tca.UserId order by case when DateAdd(Day,coalesce(c.DaysSinceLastCall,dflt.DaysSinceLastCall), tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end desc, tca.[Date] desc) r`.

The purpose of this piece is to find the "most important" call for each user.  By "most important" I basically mean the most recent, since that's generally what we're after; though there's one caveat.  If a user is part of 2 campaigns, one with an offset of 30 days and one with an offset of 60 days, they may have had 2 calls, one 32 days ago and one 38 days ago.  Though the call from 32 days ago is more recent, if that's on the campaign with the 30 day offset it's outside the window, whilst the older call from 38 days ago may be on the campaign with an offset of 60 days, meaning that it's within the window, so is more of interest (i.e. this user has been called within a campaign window).

Given the above requirement, here's how this code meets it:

- `row_number()` produces a number from 1, counting up, for each row in the (sub)query's results.  The counter is reset to 1 for each `partition`
- `partition by tca.UserId` says that we're partitioning by the user id; so for each user there will be 1 row for which `row_number()` returns 1, then for each additional row for that user there will be a consecutive number returned.
- The `order by` part of this statement defines which of each users' rows gets #1, then how the numbers progress thereafter; i.e. the first row according to the order by gets number 1, the next number 2, etc.
- `case when DateAdd(Day,coalesce(c.DaysSinceLastCall,dflt.DaysSinceLastCall), tca.[Date]) > getutcdate() then 1 else 0 end` returns 1 for calls within their campaign's window, and 0 for those outside of the window.  Since we're ordering by this result in ascending order, that says that any records within their campaign's window should be returned before any outside of their campaign's window.
- we then order by `tca.[Date] desc`; i.e. the more recent calls are returned before the later calls.
- finally, we name the output of this row number as `r` and in the outer query filter on `r = 1`; meaning that for each user we only take one row, and that's the first row according to the order criteria above; i.e. if there's a row in its campaign's window we take that, after which it's whichever call was most recent (within those in the window if there were any; then outside that window if there weren't).

Take a look at the output of the subquery to get a better idea of exactly how this works: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04543/4)

I hope that explanation makes some sense / helps you to understand the code?  Sadly I can't find a way to explain it more concisely than the code itself does; so if it doesn't make sense try playing with the code and seeing how that affects the output to see if that helps your understanding.

Comment: Thanks. Took me about 30 minutes to understand and decipher each command but I think I've managed.  One more question, I do define the accepted window from each campaign, can I define a general window for "other than" campaigns? i.e. I would like to get users that Campaign 1 calls to them were made at least 70 days back or 50 days from ANY other campaign. Also, I didn't fully understand the "ORDER BY 1/0" in the partition query. What does it mean? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries; added a tweaked version of the code to include a default, plus explanation of the windowed function (i.e. the order by piece)... Hope that makes sense; again please say if not.